# Concurrent updates to different attributes in dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a situation where 2 processes could end up updating the same dynamodb item but different attributes. Both processes don't update the entire item. For eg, if I have table with attributes A1, A2, A3 and A4, process-1 could would update A1 and process-2 would update A4. In any case the attributes that are updated by either processes are not overlapping.

I am not sure how dynamodb actually handles these concurrent writes to the same item. I was actually expecting an error (as we have no locking or a similar mechanism like updating based on version number in place) but it works just fine.

I am using Go. I created like 50 goroutines which updates A1 and another 50 goroutines to update A2 to simulate the behavior in production. It works without any issues. I just wanted to make sure this does not have any implications (other than accidentally having both processes update the same set of attributes).

Please advice. Thank you!

Comment: Could you provide some more information? Do you have a sort key in your table? What sort of operation are you making to the table. What sort of program are you making. Can't really help unless we have that info

Answer (score 0):

This is a great example of a time where it might be worth splitting these into two different items. It is difficult to know for sure without a lot more information about your schema and use case.

I say this as under the correct traffic circumstances, what you are proposing can absolutely run into DynamoDB's service limits on the number of writes per partition per second, which is 1000.

Without knowing more about your application or data model, I recommend creating an [item collection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItemCollections.html) with a sort key that you can use [the key condition expression of begins_with()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.KeyConditionExpressions.html) when doing a query if you need to read all the items in one query. Still, when writing each attribute, they each go to their own item, but they're related. Since they have the same partition key, all of the items in the item collection are stored together. Like I said, this is purely a guess to if this will be your solution without more information.

Comment: Really not giving any valuable answer. "Please change your schema was the answer in production" then we would never worry about legacy code.